# Nature of energy in a mechanical wave

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves

A passing ship creates a large wave. As it moves shoreward, the wave encounters an anchored yacht which rises up. If the yacht is prevented from falling back to its pre-wave floating position, has the wave transferred an amount of energy (equal to m*g*h) when it reaches shore?

Answer (score 2):

Yes: that energy is now missing from the wave, and won't make it to shore. You have *harvested* some of the energy content of that wave and stored it as potential energy. Variations on this effect form the basis of *wave energy* as a potential carbon-free energy source.